# kotlin + dagger 2 : Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So, I am trying to create an example, inspiring from [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) with Kotlin. I have successfully migrated to kotlin code but I getting error with my `ApplicationComponent.kt`.

```
Error:(12, 2) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.<init>(injectorFactories)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> is injected at
          com.chintansoni.android.architecturecomponentsblueprint.base.BaseActivity.dispatchingAndroidInjector
      com.chintansoni.android.architecturecomponentsblueprint.view.activity.SplashActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

I can see that issue is surfaced from AndroidInjectionModule from `import dagger.android.AndroidInjectionModule`

Let me share my code snippets.

**KotlinApplication.kt**

```
class KotlinApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeLogger()
        initializeAppInjector()
    }

    private fun initializeAppInjector() {
        AppInjector.init(this)
    }

    private fun initializeLogger() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>? {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
}
```

**AppInjector.kt**

```
object AppInjector {
    fun init(kotlinApplication: KotlinApplication) {
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .application(kotlinApplication)
                .build()
                .inject(kotlinApplication)

        kotlinApplication.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

            override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                handleActivity(activity)
            }

            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {

            }

            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {

            }

            override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

            }

            override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

            }

            override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

            }

            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

            }
        })
    }

    private fun handleActivity(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity is HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
            AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
        }
        (activity as? FragmentActivity)?.supportFragmentManager?.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                    override fun onFragmentCreated(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment,
                                                   savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
                        if (f is Injectable) {
                            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f)
                        }
                    }
                }, true)
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidInjectionModule::class), (AppModule::class), (SplashActivityModule::class)])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(kotlinApplication: KotlinApplication)
}
```

**SplashActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class SplashActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(FragmentBuildersModule::class)])
    internal abstract fun contributeSplashActivity(): SplashActivity
}
```

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getLayoutResource())
    }

    abstract fun getLayoutResource(): Int
}
```

My `SplashActivity` extends `BaseActivity`.

Comment: I had exact same issue. and Solution was in build.gradle  Can you show your app level build.gradle file?

Comment: are you using `AndroidSupportInjection` for the fragment ?

Comment: Yes @Blackbelt  I am using AndroidSupportInjection.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you resolved this specific issue, why would you use AndroidInjection at all? The code becomes much more complicated, and all these corner cases... Is there an advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Fragment` from the support library, you've to use the `HasSupportFragmentInjector` in your `KotlinApplication`:

```
class KotlinApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeLogger()
        initializeAppInjector()
    }

    private fun initializeAppInjector() {
        AppInjector.init(this)
    }

    private fun initializeLogger() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>? {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment>? {
        return dispatchingFragmentInjector
    }
}
```

also you've to install `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` instead of `AndroidInjectionModule` in your `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class), (AppModule::class), (SplashActivityModule::class)])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(kotlinApplication: KotlinApplication)
}
```

Comment: I already have them in my build.gradle. I think this is trivial and first step towards kotlin + Dagger

Comment: Though it worked, I wonder why!!
I already have it implemented `HasSupportFragmentInjector` in my Activity. Give me a min. I ma sharing my activity code.

Comment: @ChintanSoni because you do not have the right module installed anywhere and Dagger can not find an appropriate `@Provides` method for the support fragment: you either have to install it in your `ApplicationComponent` or in your `SplashActivityModule `.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. What you did with Application class wasn't necessary as my activity is already implementing `HasSupportFragmentInjector` interface. Last point of including Module of `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` instead of `AndroidInjectionModule ` was the main catch. Anyways. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was wired correctly. What I was doing wrong,

In `ApplicationComponent` I included `AndroidInjectionModule` which will only work to Inject Fragment from Android Framework.

Looking at the source of **AndroidInjectionModule**:

```
package dagger.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.internal.Beta;
import dagger.multibindings.Multibinds;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Contains bindings to ensure the usability of {@code dagger.android} framework classes. This
 * module should be installed in the component that is used to inject the {@link
 * android.app.Application} class.
 */
@Beta
@Module
public abstract class AndroidInjectionModule {
  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<Class<? extends Activity>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>>
      activityInjectorFactories();

  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<Class<? extends Fragment>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>>
      fragmentInjectorFactories();

  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<Class<? extends Service>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Service>>
      serviceInjectorFactories();

  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<
          Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends BroadcastReceiver>>
      broadcastReceiverInjectorFactories();

  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<
          Class<? extends ContentProvider>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends ContentProvider>>
      contentProviderInjectorFactories();

  private AndroidInjectionModule() {}
}
```

No mentions about Fragment from Support Library.

Now, if we look at the source of **AndroidSupportInjectionModule**:

```
package dagger.android.support;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjectionModule;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;
import dagger.internal.Beta;
import dagger.multibindings.Multibinds;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Configures bindings to ensure the usability of {@code dagger.android} and {@code
 * dagger.android.support} framework classes. This module should be installed in the root-most
 * component which will use these types.
 */
@Beta
@Module(includes = AndroidInjectionModule.class)
public abstract class AndroidSupportInjectionModule {
  @Multibinds
  abstract Map<Class<? extends Fragment>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>>
      supportFragmentInjectorFactories();

  private AndroidSupportInjectionModule() {}
}
```

It includes support for injecting `Fragment` from Support Library.

If you notice, `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` also includes `AndroidInjectionModule`. Hence, just including `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` will work perfectly.

My BaseActivity was implementing `HasSupportFragmentInjector` which only works with Support Fragment. There was no Module included into ApplicationComponent that can provide `Fragment` dependency from Support Library, which was the main issue.